# Correct usage of 'but for'?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, conditionals, conditional-perfect

Does 'but for' mean:

'If we had X (but we didn't), Y would have been the consequence'?

Or can it also mean; because we had X, as a result Y happened?

Some different examples of ***but for***:

(Case 1)

> But for a cup coffee, it was to be a productive day of writing.
>   Unfortunately, I'd run out, and spent the day craving.

(Case 2)

> But for the glass of wine I had dinner, the house work didn't get
>   done.

(Case 3)

> But for the glass of wine I had for dinner, I would have got the
>   house work done

**What is the correct usage of "but for"?**

Comment: Please feel free to edit if you feel this question can be improved.

Comment: To poop with, of course!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The preposition *But for x* be expanded as:

> if x had not existed or if x had not happened

This makes *but for* the equivalent of the third (remote) conditional where the main clause contains the *would have* construction. On this basis your third case is correct:

> But for (*If I hadn't drunk*) the glass of wine I had for dinner, I
>   would have got the house work done.

A related sense of *but for* is *with the exception of*:

> But for (*with the exception of*) the wine, everything about the meal
>   was perfect.

Neither of the above senses of *but for* works in your case 1 and 2 sentences.

Answer (score 2):

*But for* often means ‘If it hadn’t been for’. That is the case with 'But for the glass of wine I had for dinner, I would have got the house work done.' If you make a similar substitution with the other two sentences, they make no more sense than they do with *but for*.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for the first case. 'If it hadn't been for a cup of coffee, it was to be a productive day'.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

A question appeared in UG examination of English language in these words:
Rewrite the following conditional sentence using preposition " but" in the 
new sentence having same sense:
"If you you had not helped me, I would not have got success." The question posed
a difficulty not only to the students but some faculty also.
*The correct rewritten sentence is: "But for your help, I would not have got success."*

Comment: How is your answer different from other answers?

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'But for sth', it basically means that 'if sth didn't exist or without sth'. (This phrase, **but for** appeared on my test just about a few days ago, and I did it right as my teacher told me the answer.)

Example: But for the good cooperation, our teamwork would not have been successful.

Comment: True, Pisey, but this answer has already been given.

Answer (score -1):

'But for something had happened' means if the thing had not happened.
For example:- But for your help I would not have managed.
It means that-
If you had not helped me I would not have managed.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this adds anything new and useful to the accepted answer and the other two answers that already appear on this page. Can you explain?