# Can someone explain the meaning of this sentence and what "but for " implies?

Tags: idioms

I would not have worked in London in the summer **but for** being on holiday.

Comment: In re: the interpretation of this specific sentence, it's a bit confusing and self-contradictory.  Being "on holiday" means "not working"; so the expanded sentence reads "I would **not have  worked** in the summer, **except** I was already **not working**". Are you sure the copied the original right?

Comment: Sorry,I meant school holiday

Comment: Dan Bron 'Being "on holiday" means "not working"' does not cover all senses adequately (though Harry would admittedly have been better clarifying the intended sense earlier). I've known people work when they are _on holiday_ (BrE for at the seaside etc).

Answer (score 3):

"but for" is a construct used to imply something like "except for".

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but%20for):

> **but for**: *except for*

You use "but for" when you want to say, for instance, I would not have done **this**, except for **that**. Simply put, I would not have done **this**, but I did this only because of **that**.

A similar phrase for "but for" is: "had it not been for".

Also take a look at this question [here on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138019/correct-usage-of-but-for). I trust it will clarify any remaining doubts you may have.

Therefore, in your sentence, "but for" means:

> I would not have worked in London in the summer, had I not been on holiday.

Answer (score 1):

> I would not have worked in London in the summer **but for** being on
>   holiday.

I would not have worked in London in the summer(you did work in London for the summer), but for being on holiday. (if it was not for the fact that I was on holiday at that time.)

So in order to get rid of all the double and triple negatives.

> I was being on holiday in London this summer. And only being on
>   holiday allowed me to work in London.

Answer (score 0):

The construction "***but for*** X" means "***except that X prevents (or prevented) me from doing so***"; the [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/but+for) has some examples:

> **But for** *someone or something*: if it were not for someone or something.
>
> ***But for*** the railing, I'd have fallen down the stairs.
>
> ***But for*** the children, Mrs. Smith would have left her husband years ago.