# What is the meaning "would have" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

None of the days in March are the days that I **would have** gone to office,but for being on annual leave.

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact same question like 4 hours ago? Can you describe what you found unsatisfactory in the answers here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190162/can-someone-explain-the-meaning-of-this-sentence-and-what-but-for-implies ? (Please explain in ***that*** question, not ***this*** one.)

Comment: Hi.This is a new question which has been bugging me all day.Please help

Comment: It's the same question. The answer is the same.

Comment: Harry, if more of your questions get closed the system could stop you asking. Only ask each question once. If you can edit a question to make it better, then do that. But if a question is closed, don't just ask it again. We have humans involved as well as machine intelligence: duplicate questions are found and closed rather ruthlessly.

Comment: this is a legal sentence which I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: The target of the duplicate has changed. *Would have* + past-participle indicates a conditional.